# Calling a parent method in a child class returns a null value

Tags: java, inheritance

I'm trying to display the value of a variable from the parent class by using a parent method but from within a child class.

```
public class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Parent p1 = new Parent();
        p1.input();
    }
}
class Parent {
    private String name;
    public void setName(String newName) {
        name = newName;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void input() {
        String q = "hi";
        setName(q);
        Child c1 = new Child();
        c1.input();
    }
}
class Child extends Parent {
    public void input() {
        System.out.print(super.getName());
    }
}
```

I was expecting it to output `hi` but instead the output is `null`. Things I've tried:

1. Using `getName()` instead of `super.getName()` in the child class.
2. Using `Parent p2 = new Parent();` and then `p2.getName()` in the child class.
3. Using `protected String name;` in the parent class.

None of these seem to work; all of them still output `null` in the end. Help?

Comment: you have **two** unrelated objects.

Answer (score 5):

You're creating a Child object within a Parent object, and you're setting the *current* parent object's name field, but ***not*** the Parent of the Child, meaning you've more than one Parent object being created -- one whose name field is being set, and the other (the parent of the child) whose name field is never set, but is tested.

As a side bit, a Parent class should not be doing this sort of thing. It should be child "agnostic".

Answer (score 3):

When you write: "child c1 = new child()", you're making an entirely new instance. This new instance has value `null` for its `name` field: The constructor of child isn't there, therefore you get the default constructor (which calls the parent class constructor and nothing else).  Your parent class also has no constructor, so it also does nothing, which leaves your `name` field at its default value of `null`.

You then call the `input` method on this instance. Because the actual type of this instance is `child`, the `input()` method defined in your `child` class runs, which prints the value of the `name` field, which is `null`.

Yes, there's ANOTHER instance (of type `parent`), which has a `name` field set to 'Hi', but you're not calling the `input` method on that instance. You're calling the `input` method of the instance you create in line `child c1 = new child();`.

Answer (score 2):

This happening as a new and separte `Child` object is created when you did `Child c1 = new Child();` which inherits the `name` property from the parent class `Parent`, whose inherited property `name` is not set and is `null`. The `p1` in the `main` is a totally different instance whose values are not shared with the `c1` instance.

> Using getName() instead of super.getName() in the child class.

Both of these will result in `null` as the `name` is inherited from the parent class `Parent` and it is not initialized. The `Parent` object you have initialized in the `main` method is a totally different instance and whose properties is not referred by the `child` instance in the `input` method.

> Using Parent p2 = new Parent(); and then p2.getName() in the child
>   class.

Again you are creating a separate instance of `Parent` and since you have not initialized the `name` value of the `p2` instance `p2.getName()` will return null.

> Using protected String name; in the parent class.

`protected` simply is an access modifier, it won't help you to initialize the `name` property inherited from the `Parent` class.

Here it is visually:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answer. I get it now why it returns a null value, but I have no idea how to remedy it. The code I made was literally just me trying to figure out how to call a parent variable from a child class. Care to teach me the proper syntax of how to do that?

Comment: The child class needs to have a constructor that takes the desired parent object as a parameter, and sets the parent (which should be a class member, and not just a variable in the method).  Then when you create the child in the parent class, you'll do something like `Child c1 = new Child(this)`, which passes a reference to the parent object into the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Following up on a comment I left, since code formatting is very limited in comments.  So the main issue here is that the child doesn't just need to have *a* parent.  The child needs to have **the exact desired object** as a parent.  The way this is typically done is via a constructor.  So I'd make the child class look like this:

```
class Child extends Parent {
    private Parent parent;

    public Child(Parent parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public void input() {
        System.out.print(parent.getName());
    }
}
```

Then, in your parent class, you'd have:

```
public void input() {
    String q = "hi";
    setName(q);
    Child c1 = new Child(this);
    c1.input();
}
```

Comment: I see that I have so much more to learn before I proceed. I think I jumped the gun and didn't really pay attention on how to use constructors. This has been most helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just to give you another small sample to work with:

```
public class main { 
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        Parent p1 = new Parent(); 
        p1.input();
        Child c1 = (Child)P1; //this is a type cast, which is possible due to what is known as polymorphism
        c1.input();
    } 
}

class Parent {

    private String name;

    public void setName(String newName) {
        name = newName; 
    } 

    public String getName() { 
        return name; 
    } 

    public void input() { 
        String q = "hi"; 
        setName(q); 
    } 
} 

class Child extends Parent { 
    public void input() { 
        System.out.print(super.getName()); 
    } 
}
```

In this tiny sample (based on your own) you create just one instance of parent. Then you type cast that, into the c1 variable as a Child. So when you call `input ()` on it. It uses the implementation from the Child class, rather than from parent.

It also assumes that you wish to use the polymorphism from outside of the actual class (e.g. in the main function in this case).